# What does (type1)+(type2) means using GetType().ToString()?

Tags: c#, types, tostring, gettype

I'm writing a little Console app to test some basic MS ProjectServer interop. I can connect to the server with no problems, and I was trying to refactor one of my `for (int i = 0; i < projectDataSet.Project.Count; i++)` loops for a `foreach (var project in projectDataSet.Project)` one.

When I do the `for`, the type of `projectDataSet.Project` is `SvcProject.ProjectDataSet.ProjectDataTable`. So, I do the following:

```
projectClient.ReadProject(projectDataSet.Project[i].PROJ_UID,
    SvcProject.DataStoreEnum.WorkingStore);
```

To get the Project object I need.

But when I do the `foreach` variation, the type of the object `project` is `SvcProject.ProjectDataSet+ProjectRow`. I don't know how to handle this. What does it means, exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that `type2` is nested in `type1`

```
class type1
{
   public class type2 { }
}
```

To demonstrate this:

```
foreach (var t in typeof (A).GetNestedTypes(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic))
    Console.WriteLine(t.FullName);

class A
{
    private class B
    {
    }

    protected class C
    {
    }

    internal class D
    {
    }

    public class E
    {

    }
}
```

Output:

```
YourAssembly.A+B
YourAssembly.A+C
YourAssembly.A+D
YourAssembly.A+E
```

Comment: Thanks. And how I access the props of, say, an E object in a foreach loop? Like: 

var list = new List<E>();
list.Add(new E());
foreach(var myVar in list) 
 Console.WriteLine("{0}", "What should I put here to retrieve an useful prop?");

Comment: @BrunoSaboia:  It's the same way you would for any other `Type`.  If you don't know how, please ask another question because it's not really in the scope of the question you've asked here.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I was thinking of using Reflections, but this is overkill and if that's the case, it is best to stick to the for loop